# Download pdf from Url and save it to sd card

Tags: android, download, android-storage

I have wrote this code for download `pdf` from `url` and file `url` is this-

```
 String fileURL= "http://www.vivekananda.net/PDFBooks/History_of_India.pdf";
```

**Code this**

```
  public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {

    try {

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.getResponseCode();
        c.connect();

        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but this shows file not found exception with response code 405.I dont know why this happened.Please help..!!

This is my code where i had create file in sd card-

**Code this**

```
  public void createPdfFile(){
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
                folder.mkdir();
                 file = new File(folder, "storrage_data.pdf");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }        
    }`
```

After this i am calling download method in thread like this from onResume(); beacuse from onCreate it will give error "Network On Main Thread".where i am wrong now i don't konw :(

**Code this**

```
 public void downloadFile(){        

     new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {             
         Downloader.DownloadFile(url, file);
          showPdf();

            }
        }).start();   


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason is the folder in which you want to does not exist. First check if it exist. Create it if not. Then create fileoutputstream and write to it.

Comment: What are you sending in "directory" argument?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the DownloadManager. There are too many problems that can arise during download to handle all of them yourself. Just think of temporary loss of connectivity in the middle of download...
Below is some code I pulled out of my app and slightly modified to get rid of parts you don't need.

```
public void downloadAndOpenPdf(String url,final File file) {
    if(!file.isFile()) {
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        req.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
        req.setTitle("Some title");

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                unregisterReceiver(this);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    openPdfDocument(file);
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        dm.enqueue(req);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        openPdfDocument(file);
    }
}

public boolean openPdfDocument(File file) {
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    try {
        startActivity(target);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No PDF reader found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What i have to give in file parameter? if you are talking about file created in sd card so it will be empty till  file download.Can you send me full code download and save pdf in sd card and then open it.

Comment: It is  where to save the downloaded PDF. The check that it does not exist is done just in case the user downloading the same file again. In my app there is a one-to-one mapping between URL and file name, so if the file exists, the URL was downloaded earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Now you need to download your pdf file to External storage or wherever you want to download and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this code and try again.

`//c.setRequestMethod("GET");
 //c.setDoOutput(true);
 //c.getResponseCode();
 //c.connect();`

I think `URL.openConnection()` has description of connection already, so `c.connect()` isn't necessary.

Comment: it has been done .Error was occurred because pdf url was not correct..!!

Comment: you mean `String fileURL= "http://www.vivekananda.net/PDFBooks/History_of_India.pdf";` is incorrect? But I made it with this url...